# svn checkout not working when using . for path

Tags: svn

My problem is this : I created a svn project on my local machine.When I checkout using

```
svn co file:///pathname .
```

and then do

```
ls
```

It does not show the checked out directory.

When I do

```
svn co file:///pathname
```

and then do

```
ls
```

it works fine. Can someone explain why the 1st method fails to checkout? Here is a MWE.

```
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing$ svnadmin create project1
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing$ ls 
project1
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing$ mkdir folder1
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing$ cd folder1/
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing/folder1$ svn co file:///home/t326/Desktop/Testing/project1 .
Checked out revision 0.
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing/folder1$ ls
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing/folder1$ svn co file:///home/t326/Desktop/Testing/project1 
Checked out revision 0.
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing/folder1$ ls
project1
t326@t326:~/Desktop/Testing/folder1$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `svn co file:///pathname .`, it instructs svn to use *current* directory as top directory for checkout. You do not see any files because there are no files in repository so far. If there were files, then they would be present in current directory after the checkout. Anyway, you should see with `ls -a` that directory `.svn` appeared in current directory which means that checkout succeeded.

Comment: Why don't I see the folder project1 when I do  `svn co file:///pathname .`  what is the difference in the 2 commands?

Comment: `project1` is *not* part of the repository (unlike files which you add with `svn add`), it is an external name. When you checkout, you specify some directory to clone all files from _inside_ the repository. If you `svn co file:///tmp/project1 blablabla`, then it will clone all files into directory `blablabla`. If you `svn co file:///tmp/project1 .`, it will clone all files into current directory. If you `svn co file:///tmp/project1`, it will clone all files into directory which name is the last component of the URI (`project1`); this feature is just a shorthand.

Comment: Okay I understand now. I disagree with one thing though, project1 IS part of the project. I did  `svnadmin create project1`, surely project1 is part of the repository? No?

Comment: No, it isn't. `/tmp/project1` in `svnadmin create /tmp/project1` is a path in local filesystem where you would like to initialize the project. It doesn't assign any name to the project.